# Configute ASP Net Core 2 middleware for Bearer token authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, bearer-token

I have a mobile app (built in xamarin) that uses Xamarin.Auth to let the user authenticate against Microsofts Oauth (https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf).
This works finns, and I retrieve an access_token back to my mobile app.

Now, I have created an ASP NET Core 2.0 Web API in order to serve as my application backend. I want this backend to validate that someone with a valid MS-token is comunicating with it.
I'm passing my token from the client with the header "Authorization" "Bearer XYZ....".

Now to my problem. I'm a bit confused about how to configure my Web API. In the ConfigureServices method, should I use "AddJwtBearer(..)" or "AddOpenIdConnect(..)" or "AddMicrosoftAccount(...)" ?
When Using Microsoft account, my webapi just redirects me to the MS login witch is NOT what I want. If no valid token is given, I want my backend to return "Unauthorized".
When Using the JwtBearer, my backend fails with the message "No SecurityTokenValidator available for token".

My config for jwt:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
{
  jwtOptions.Authority = "https://login.live.com";
  jwtOptions.Audience = "myClientId";
  jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
});
```

and in Configure, I have app.UseAuthentication() Before app.UseMvc()

Where am I going wrong?
Best regards Andreas